# Python Bottle Micro-Web Framework

Tags: python, web, frameworks, bottle

Ok, so I've gone to the http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/ website, and tried following their instructions for including the bottle.py framework, and do the little test web service test they have on the site.

The problem I'm having is that the python script does not recognize the "from bottle import route, run, template", so the code does not execute. I can't find anything to show HOW to properly include the bottle framework.

I've gone to YouTube, multiple posts on StackOverflow, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Some info: I'm using Eclipse with PyDev, and I'm running on Windows 7 64 bit. Also, I write in other languages (Java, C#, Objective-C) but I'm new to Python, so maybe I'm making a newbie mistake...?

Comment: Is it a package in the same directory? Or maybe you want to put it in the python path of your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the Botte package. Citing the "Download and Install" section from the [Bottle web site](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/):

> Install the latest stable release via [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bottle) (`easy_install -U bottle`) or download [bottle.py](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/raw/master/bottle.py) (unstable) into your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

If `easy_install bottle` didn't work, try `pip install bottle`.